# Toolbar UI Login - Inbox by Gmail App

Tags: android-layout, android, material-design

I'm looking at different variations of login screens which have material design elements.

I found the Inbox app quite interesting.

The toolbar (action bar) appears to be mid screen. And the (action bar) snaps up to the right position when editing text.

Questions:

Is this a standard behaviour across 5.0?

How do they achieve this?

[image: Inbox by Gmail - Login]

[image: Toolbar snaps up on edit]

Answer (score 0):

The UI element you are seeing on the top, playing the role of an ActionBar is actually the [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) widget.

> A Toolbar is a generalization of action bars for use within application layouts. While an action bar is traditionally part of an Activity's opaque window decor controlled by the framework, a Toolbar may be placed at any arbitrary level of nesting within a view hierarchy. An application may choose to designate a Toolbar as the action bar for an Activity using the setActionBar() method.

You can have multiple toolbars in an Activity. The toolbars can have different heights. The standard height of the toolbar in portrait is 56dp.

Update:

Default height:
Mobile Landscape: 48dp
Mobile Portrait: 56dp
Tablet/Desktop: 64dp

For extended app bars, the height is equal to the default height plus content increment(s).
[image: extended app bar]

You can read more from the [Material design specification.](http://www.google.co.uk/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar)

For implementing it you just set the `layout_height` attribute in the layout file. Of course extracting the number as a dimension resource is always a good idea.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question above, I'm more curious about the change in height of the toolbar. Thanks